# How to return a JSONArray from JavascriptInterface

Tags: javascript, android, json, arrays

I was trying to capture the form data of a HTML using Javascript and return them to Java as JSONArray, but it seems that the JSONArray is not correctly returned to Java in the JavascriptInterface.

The Javascript works perfectly in the Chrome, so the problem should be either on the java side or on the interface.

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: FeArray=document.getElementsByTagName('input')");
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: JSJSONArray = []");
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: for(i=0;i<FeArray.length;i++) { fe=FeArray[i]; JSJSONArray.push({'id':fe.id,'type':fe.type,'checked':fe.checked,'value':fe.value});}");
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: JSBridge.transferFromJS2Java(JSJSONArray)");
```

The transferFromJS2Java is a @JavascriptInterface function implemented as follows:

```
public class JSBridge{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void transferFromJS2Java(String data) {
        mJSONArray = new JSONArray(data);
    }
}
```

Here mJSONArray is a global variable.

I think probably I cannot copy the JSONArray in this way. Is there any better way that I can copy the JSJSONArray from Javascript to Java?

Comment: Expect a `String` which you can parse in Android.

Comment: Try to change the parameter for `String data` and do the conversion within the method `mJSONArray = new JSONArray(data);`. For these types I do not think Java does automatic conversion coming from a webview. By the way make sure you call these `loadUrl` when the page has been completely loaded.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexBcn. I call all the loadUrl functions in $onPageFinished$. Now the problem is that the String can't be converted to JSONArray Directly. I noticed that there are some we that first convert the String to a JSONObject, then convert the Object to an Array, but the problem is that I even can't print the "data" out as a String. When I try to print out the parameter data, it just returns "undefined".

Comment: Does `FeArray.length` contain the right count of your inputs?

Comment: @greenapps. The FeArray.length and JSJSONArray.length contain the right count, i.e. 20, but when I pass JSJSONArray or JSJSONArray[0] to the JSBridge, it just get undefined in the Java side.

Comment: Do not pass a json array or object as others already told you. Just pass a string with the json text. So change the parameter to a string and start with a predefined string to transfer. Mmmm. I see now that you already have a String data on java side. But on javascript side you pass a json array. You should pass a json text string there.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. I didn't know that I need to explicitly convert the JSONArray to String on the JavaScript side. Now it works.

Comment: Well i would not have used JSJSONArray to begin with but build the json text myself. You have all in the push() parameter. I presumed you were going to do that too. But ... Nothing wrong with yours. Hmmmm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is as I mentioned in the discussion, to stringify the JSONArray in Javascript:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: var JSString = JSON.stringify(JSJSONArray);");
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: JSBridge.transferFormData(JSString)");
```

Then on the Java side, convert the String back to JSONArray using the second code segment in the question.